# Sound settings refuse to be saved; Audio works as it should

Tags: pulseaudio, settings

Every time I log out or reboot, the sound output settings change from HDMI to the native speakers.

I've tried Googling the last couple of days, but the only things I can find are answers for if the audio doesn't work at all.

My audio works fine, Ubuntu 16.04 just refuses to save my preferred output.

Comment: did you check EQEnabled and keep settings

Comment: Thank you for the reply. A few Google searches told me nothing of this cryptic messages you wrote. Would you mind elaborating? :-)

Answer (score 3):

- Case 1 - *Tick `EQEnabled` and `keep settings`*
- Case 2 - *If it not save open dash and search for `startup application` search for `pulse audio sound system` if it disabled enable it.*
- Case 3 - *if the `pulse audio sound system` not found add click `add`*

> In name section type: PulseAudio Sound System. 
> In command type:
>   start-pulseaudio-x11. 
> In comment type: Start the PulseAudio Sound
>   System.

Comment: Brilliant. That fixed it. Thank you! :-) I had to use case 3.

Comment: Jupp.. Today when I loggen in to my computer, the same problem came back. Tried also a reboot, and what do you know. Same there..

Comment: @fleppmar Honestly i don't know the reason but try to upgrade to new distro  or reinstall pulse audio yesterday pulse generates  a new update.

Comment: Allright, I will. Thank you. The OS itself is quite slow. It will take from 1-5seconds after I click an icon to something happens, and sometimes I must right click to open a program. So maybe a complete reinstall of Ubuntu is necessary..

Comment: Same happens to me on `Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS`. `Sound-settings -> Output -> Connector (then changing to LineOut)`. It is not saved. After restart it gets the old value. Maybe it is related to this issue: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/pulseaudio/+bug/1334329